# Count Korean characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I want to be able to count how many Korean letters there are in the input, like I am doing with the English letters and numbers:

```
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0

num = input("type something ")

for i in num:
    if(i.isupper()):
        a=a+1
    elif(i.islower()):
        b=b+1
    elif(i.isdigit()):
        c=c+1


print("uppercase letters: ",a)
print("lowercase letters: ",b)
print("numbers: ",c)
print("korean letters: ",d)
```

But I have no idea how I should do this, do I have to incorporate `ord()` somehow?

Comment: ***All*** characters are Unicode characters.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to count [Hangul codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers#Hangul_in_Unicode)?

Comment: Unrelated pro tip: don't name your variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. The future you will thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your question would also be improved with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Note: `isupper()` and `islower()` return true for far more than just English letters.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking how to count [Hangul codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers#Hangul_in_Unicode), you'll need to take the `ord()` value of the character and see if it is in any of the documented ranges:

```
hangul_ranges = (
    range(0xAC00, 0xD7A4),  # Hangul Syllables (AC00–D7A3)
    range(0x1100, 0x1200),  # Hangul Jamo (1100–11FF)
    range(0x3130, 0x3190),  # Hangul Compatibility Jamo (3130-318F)
    range(0xA960, 0xA980),  # Hangul Jamo Extended-A (A960-A97F)
    range(0xD7B0, 0xD800),  # Hangul Jamo Extended-B (D7B0-D7FF)
)
is_hangul = lambda c: any(ord(c) in r for r in hangul_ranges)
```

Then use `is_hangul(i)`.

As it happens, no Hangul character is ever considered uppercase, lowercase or a digit, but take into account that those three categories encompass far more than just *English*; the Unicode 8.0 standard has:

- [1613 uppercase letters](https://codepoints.net/search?gc%5B%5D=Lu),
- [1984 lowercase letters](https://codepoints.net/search?gc%5B%5D=Ll),
- and [678 digits](https://codepoints.net/search?nt%5B%5D=De&nt%5B%5D=Di).